# Postgres jsonb_object_agg returns only the last row

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate

I want to transform a JSON table on a JSON list.

This code :

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    varMyJson jsonb;
BEGIN

    varMyJson := '[{"Field1":"Value1"},{"Field2":"Value2"}]'::jsonb;
    RAISE NOTICE 'varMyJson : %', varMyJson;
    
    SELECT jsonb_object_agg(a.key, a.value)
    INTO varMyJson
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 'MyKey' as key, JsonString.value
        FROM jsonb_array_elements(varMyJson) JsonString
    ) a;
    RAISE NOTICE 'varMyJson : %', varMyJson;

END
$$
```

returns :

```
NOTICE:  varMyJson : [{"Field1": "Value1"}, {"Field2": "Value2"}]
NOTICE:  varMyJson : {"MyKey": {"Field2": "Value2"}}
```

But, I want this :

```
{"MyKey":{"Field1":"Value1"},"MyKey":{"Field2": "Value2"}}
```

I don't understand why it dosn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a `jsonb` object with duplicate keys. Your `json_object_agg` function will work expectedly when your keys are unique.

You can get your desired results in a `jsonb` array:

```sql
with data as (
   select '[{"Field1":"Value1"},{"Field2":"Value2"}]'::jsonb as items
) 

select json_agg(v) from (
    select jsonb_build_object('myKey', jsonb_array_elements(items)) as v from data
) x
```

Comment: Or use `json` instead of `jsonb`.

Comment: json_object_agg works in a simple "SELECT" statement but doesn't work with a "INTO variable" statement. Maybe it is a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT json_object_agg('MyKey', JsonString.value)
  FROM json_array_elements('[{"Field1": "Value1"}, {"Field2": "Value2"}]' :: json) JsonString
```

result = `{ "MyKey" : {"Field1": "Value1"}, "MyKey" : {"Field2": "Value2"} }`

Comment: Actually `jsonb` does not allow duplicate keys, `json` does.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver : agree with you, answer updated accordingly

Comment: json_object_agg works in a simple "SELECT" statement but doesn't work with a "INTO variable" statement. Maybe it is a bug ?

Comment: @Ben : very surprising ! What is the error message ? Your variable must be of type `json`

Comment: @Edouard : indeed, it's OK if we use everything in json (type, functions). But we can have weird results when it's mixed. It seems almost random. Examples :
`SELECT
 json_object_agg('MyKey',JsonString.*)
 , jsonb_object_agg('MyKey',JsonString.*)
FROM jsonb_array_elements('[{"Field1":"Value1"},{"Field2":"Value2"}]'::jsonb) JsonString;`
and
`SELECT json_object_agg(a.key, a.value)
 INTO varMyJson
 FROM
 (
  SELECT 'MyKey' as key, JsonString.value
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(varMyJson::jsonb) JsonString
 ) a;`

Comment: @Edouard : And I don't understand the logic of this difference in behavior between json_object_agg and jsonb_object_agg.

Comment: The difference is : `json` allows duplicated keys in the same object, `jsonb` doesn't. `jsonb_object_agg` is going to arbitrary remove some duplicated keys, `json_object_agg` won't. Generally speaking, I would recommend you to not design json/jsonb objects with duplicated keys.